# While Loop, Pandas and Applying a Function to Column Values of Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, while-loop

I have a tricky situation:

I have a dataframe with a series of columns, and I need to apply a function to each row within a particular column, where it takes the value of the column, finds which bin it is in, and results a corresponding value assigned to the bins.

What I code I currently have has the parameter where I specify the row number and it returns a single result. However, I'd like it to be that I can apply the function to the entire column of the dataframe and pass over each row, and return the results of every row. I tried to use the .apply() but I was getting back the 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty()...etc.'

Current code:

```
ColumnData = df.DataColumn
AIndex = 0
ABCRow = 0
AStep = 1
Bin = range(ColumnData.min(), ColumnData.max(), Astep)
GroupV = df.groupby(df.cut(df.DataColumn, Bin).ABC
ABCMean = GroupV.mean()

def Function (Row):
    while AIndex <= ColumnData.max():
        if AIndex <= ColumnData.iloc[Row] <= AIndex+=AStep:
            ABCMeanVal = ABCMean.iloc[ABCRow]
        AIndex += 1
        ACBRow += 1
    return ABCMeanVal 

Function (0)
1.5
```

However, as you can see, the function only works when you enter the index of the column individually, and I'm not sure how to make it so that it will pass through each cell of the column and return all the results. I thought about a while loop inside it, or a secondary function, but I can't figure it out. (I am also only a beginner in Python, so not confident in it yet).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to post a minimum toy example, but creating a fake dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column A': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e'},
 'Value': {0: 34, 1: 50, 2: 86, 3: 100, 4: 2},
 'bins': {0: Interval(32, 34, closed='right'),
  1: Interval(48, 50, closed='right'),
  2: Interval(84, 86, closed='right'),
  3: Interval(98, 100, closed='right'),
  4: Interval(0, 2, closed='right')}})
```

Then, if you are looking to calculate the bin for the value, you can use pd.cut().
Also suggest to use vectorized calculations instead of loops.

```
df['bins'] = pd.cut(df['Value'],bins=np.arange(start=0,stop=df['Value'].max()+1,step=2))
```

Resulting in:

```
Column A  Value       bins
0        a     34   (32, 34]
1        b     50   (48, 50]
2        c     86   (84, 86]
3        d    100  (98, 100]
4        e      2     (0, 2]
```

Comment: Hope this answer give you a hint on how you can resolve your problem, if is the case please mark or provide feedback. Thanks